# Lost my connector

Tags: pcb, identification, connector

I had opened my Rotimatic machine for some repairs. I was taking pictures along the way of things that I unplug. While putting it back together, I realized that I am missing the connector the FFC (I think). Can anyone guide me to find the replacement? What kind of a connector I am looking for and where should I buy it from?

This is the picture before I took it apart:

[image]

And this is the picture now:

[image]

Comment: 0. The delicate part you want to find is there somewhere. 1. Do not walk or step anywhere. 2. Do not move your chair, even if it has castors. 3. If you have a bright torch to hand, use it to look around on the floor.

Comment: 4. Slowly move your hands through your hair. Has is somehow sprung up there? Now try to find where it has moved to. 5. Look at your clothes - has it stuck there somewhere? 5a. Make sure no-one is around and remove outer clothes slowly, starting at the top. Ideally, you will be standing in a blank white room so that no small component piece can escape unobserved. 6) You should get the idea as to how to progress from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and measure the pad pitch, it can be either 0.5 or 1mm.
The vendor is Wurth Elektric, and here is a link to the 30 position, 0.5mm variant:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/w%C3%BCrth-elektronik/687330124422/2811180?utm_adgroup=FFC%2C%20FPC%20%28Flat%20Flexible%29%20Connectors&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping_Product_Connectors%2C%20Interconnects_NEW&utm_term=&utm_content=FFC%2C%20FPC%20%28Flat%20Flexible%29%20Connectors&utm_id=bi_cmp-420511935_adg-1299623108470404_ad-81226519274362_pla-4584826056668136:aud-813320050_dev-c_ext-_prd-2811180&msclkid=e7af8ff6f03a11d461d0ea1da7cdd446

Comment: thanks! that worked!